# Column Name inside column of dataframe in spark with scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[image]I am using spark with Scala. 2.4.3

My salesperson Dataframe looks like: it has total **54** **salesperson, i took example of only 3 column**

```
Schema of SalesPerson table.
root
 |-- col: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- SalesPerson_1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SalesPerson_2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SalesPerson_3: string (nullable = true)
```

Data of Salesperson view.

```
     SalesPerson_1|SalesPerson_2|SalesPerson_3
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    [Customer_1793,  Customer_202,  Customer_2461]
    [Customer_2424, Customer_130, Customer_787]
    [Customer_1061, Customer_318, Customer_706]
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

My salesplace dataframe looks like

```
Schema of salesplace
 
 root
 |-- Place: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Customer: string (nullable = true)

Data of salesplace
Place|Customer
Online| Customer_1793
Retail| Customer_1793
Retail| Customer_130
Online| Customer_130
Online| Customer_2461
Retail| Customer_2461
Online| Customer_2461
```

i am trying to check which customer from Salesperson table are available in SalesPlace table.
with two `additional column shows customer belong to  salesperson`

and count of customer occurance in SalesPlace table, for

Expected Output:

```
CustomerBelongstoSalesperson|Customer     |occurance|
SalesPerson_1               |Customer_1793|2
SalesPerson_2               |Customer_130 |2 
SalesPerson_3               |Customer_2461|3
SalesPerson_2               |Customer_202 |0
SalesPerson_1               |Customer_2424|0
SalesPerson_1               |Customer_1061|0
SalesPerson_2               |Customer_318 |0
SalesPerson_3               |Customer_787 |0
```

Code:

```
Error:
The number of aliases supplied in the AS clause does not match the number of columns output by the UDTF expected 54 aliases but got Salesperson,Customer ;
```

It seems little critical in spark.
i am not sure if it is possible to bring columnname inside column as value....
May someone please help me with some idea how to do this........
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

### Load the test data provided

```scala
 val data1 =
      """
        |salesperson1          |  salesperson2
        |Customer_17         |Customer_202
        |Customer_24         |Customer_130
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS1 = data1.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df1 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS1)
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
    /**
      * +------------+------------+
      * |salesperson1|salesperson2|
      * +------------+------------+
      * |Customer_17 |Customer_202|
      * |Customer_24 |Customer_130|
      * +------------+------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- salesperson1: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- salesperson2: string (nullable = true)
      */

    val data2 =
      """
        |Place  |Customer
        |shop  |Customer_17
        |Home  |Customer_17
        |shop  |Customer_17
        |Home  |Customer_130
        |Shop  |Customer_202
      """.stripMargin
    val stringDS2 = data2.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df2 = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("nullValue", "null")
      .csv(stringDS2)
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()
    /**
      * +-----+------------+
      * |Place|Customer    |
      * +-----+------------+
      * |shop |Customer_17 |
      * |Home |Customer_17 |
      * |shop |Customer_17 |
      * |Home |Customer_130|
      * |Shop |Customer_202|
      * +-----+------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Place: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Customer: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### `Unpivot` and `left join`

```scala
  val stringCol = df1.columns.map(c => s"'$c', cast(`$c` as string)").mkString(", ")
    val processedDF = df1.selectExpr(s"stack(${df1.columns.length}, $stringCol) as (Salesperson, Customer)")
    processedDF.show(false)
    /**
      * +------------+------------+
      * |Salesperson |Customer    |
      * +------------+------------+
      * |salesperson1|Customer_17 |
      * |salesperson2|Customer_202|
      * |salesperson1|Customer_24 |
      * |salesperson2|Customer_130|
      * +------------+------------+
      */

    processedDF.join(df2, Seq("Customer"), "left")
      .groupBy("Customer")
      .agg(count("Place").as("Occurance"), first("Salesperson").as("Salesperson"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +------------+---------+------------+
      * |Customer    |Occurance|Salesperson |
      * +------------+---------+------------+
      * |Customer_130|1        |salesperson2|
      * |Customer_17 |3        |salesperson1|
      * |Customer_202|1        |salesperson2|
      * |Customer_24 |0        |salesperson1|
      * +------------+---------+------------+
      */
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ...... but it is not counting occurance correctly. All my data are in table view.... Please suggest. for occurance it is showing 0 for all.

Comment: I think there is some problem in join then. check the output of `processedDF.join(df2, Seq("Customer"), "left")`

Comment: I'm not using split anywhere in the answer. given `SalesPerson` as df1 and `salesPlace` as df2, the answer can be achieved using `Unpivot and left join` section of my answer

Comment: In Column salesperson it is showing value as col.... col....col.......instead of Salesperson1...2 etc.... Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Are you using the same dataset with the same column name given in the question? If yes it should work. If there is any change please update the description

Comment: Hi Someshwar, i have edited the question with more clear picture..... Please help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219093/discussion-between-someshwar-kale-and-dataquest5).